# Does HTML Have An "Include/Import" Function?

Tags: html, import, include

I am developing a static website using HTML/CSS. I have 7 pages in my website and each page has the exact same header content. Is there some sort of import/include capability in HTML?

Here is an example of the kind of thing I would be looking for (note I completely made up the syntax):

[Source (header.html)]

```
<html>
    <head><title>Source Page</title></head>
    <body>
        <div id="myheader">Hello, World!</div>
    <body>
</html>
```

[Page That Imports From Source]

```
<html>
    <head><title>My Title</title></head>
    <body>
        <div import="id:myheader;source:url('header.html');"/>
    <body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Jan

Comment: No; but you could use a server-side scripting solution such as [tag:php], which does.

Comment: Is there a reason you must use only static HTML?

Comment: Yeah. I am working in an environment that doesn't have the server setup so I can only use the local filesystem right now. If there is a server-side solution then I guess I can set it up and test it later.

Comment: you can't install webserver/PHP locally?  Most developers do.  why wait for the environment when you can bring the environment to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as such, no.  There are several options, in order of accessibility and ease of use:

1. [Server-side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) (assuming your static file server supports them - most do).
2. [`iframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe)
3. Single Page Application style (requires JavaScript).
4. [`framesets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/frameset) (Legacy, avoid if possible).

### Examples

#### SSI

```
<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->
```

#### `iframes`

```
<!-- Assuming HTML5 -->
<iframe src="header.html" seamless></iframe>
```

#### Javascript

```
<script>
// We have a magic ajax function
ajax("header.html", function(data) {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = data;
});
</script>
```

#### `framesets`

Just don't :-)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide an example using #3? Is this server side javascript?

Comment: @JanTacci - Examples provided - the JavaScript solution would be *client-side* (since you say you want a simple static server).

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML does not offer such functionality. However, you can achieve the result using either server-side (many options here, depending on your server setup) or client-side (JavaScript, load the extra content with AJAX) solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same with HTML templates.....if you are using dreamweaver then create 1 .dwt file for your header footer and common layout accross the site..........it will be included automatically to all of your pages.....:)

no need of any server side scripting just plain html......................